# Create a vector from repetitons of items from a matrix

Tags: r

I have a data frame m

```
A   2
B   3
C   4
```

and I want to create a data frame like

```
A 1
A 2
B 1
B 2
B 3
C 1
C 2
C 3
C 4
```

Any help? Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: That doesn't look like a matrix. Do you mean a data frame? A matrix can only hold one of numeric *or* characters.

Comment: Also, in future, don't paste something you think is sufficient to describe your data. Use `dput(foo)` instead, where `foo` is your data object. That way we can reproduce exactly the object you are using.

Comment: -1 There are several problems here.  1) Your sample data and results don't look like a matrix.  2) Your edit has fundamentally changed the question, after three people have already answered.

Comment: Sorry for changing the question. Newbie. Wont happen again.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your original question can be answered by:

```
text <- LETTERS[1:3]
n <- 2:4

rep(text, times=n)

[1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C"
```

---

Your new question is quite different:

```
df <- data.frame(
  text <- LETTERS[1:3],
  n <- 2:4
)  

data.frame(
    text = rep(df$text, times=df$n),
    seq  = sequence(df$n)
)

  text seq
1    A   1
2    A   2
3    B   1
4    B   2
5    B   3
6    C   1
7    C   2
8    C   3
9    C   4
```

Answer (score 3):

Assuming `m` is a data frame:

```
m <- data.frame(V1 = LETTERS[1:3], V2 = 2:4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

This will do what you want:

```
with(m, rep(V1, times = V2))
```

e.g.

```
> with(m, rep(V1, times = V2))
[1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C"
```

**Edit:** To address the edit made by the OP, try the following:

```
with(m, data.frame(X1 = rep(V1, times = V2), 
                   X2 = unlist(lapply(V2, seq_len))))
```

Which produces:

```
>  with(m, data.frame(X1 = rep(V1, times = V2), 
+                        X2 = unlist(lapply(V2, seq_len))))
  X1 X2
1  A  1
2  A  2
3  B  1
4  B  2
5  B  3
6  C  1
7  C  2
8  C  3
9  C  4
```

Or more succinctly via `sequence()` — as per @Andrie's Answer (which I also keep forgetting about):

```
with(m, data.frame(X1 = rep(V1, times = V2), X2 = sequence(V2)))
```

Answer (score 3):

`rep` accepts vectors. Try this:

```
dat <- data.frame(V1 = letters[1:3], V2 = 2:4)

rep(dat[, 1], dat[, 2])


> rep(dat[, 1], dat[, 2])
[1] a a b b b c c c c
```

Answer (score 2):

@Andrie's answer is the only one so far that answers your new question.  There may be a better way to do this but:

```
m <- data.frame(V1 = LETTERS[1:3], V2 = 2:4, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
library(plyr)
ddply(m,"V1",function(x) data.frame(V2=seq(x[,2])))
```

Comment: Did you mean `library(plyr)`?  Ah, I see that `library(reshape)` depends on `plyr` so this gets loaded correctly.

Comment: A better way to use `plyr` is to make use of `adply` instead of `ddply`, as follows: `adply(m,1,function(x) data.frame(V1=x[,1],V2=seq(x[,2])))[,-1]`.  This means you don't have to construct your `m$row` column.